# Badge Requirements in Election

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, meta, election

Over on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), there are badge requirements for nomination to be moderator including Civic Duty, Strunk & White, Deputy and Convention ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3)). These requirements are designed to ensure that nominees have a correct understanding for the policies and style of the site.

Obviously imposing those restrictions on [Mi Yodeya's election](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/election) will severly limit the pool (to just me and Shmuel Brin as of now). However, I think the reasoning behind the rule on SO is sound.

As such, I request a requirement for the [Quorum](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/62/quorum) badge be added to the current election. It's not much, but I think any mod we elect should at least have this badge, indicating that they have participated in [meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/), the breeding ground of site policy. Perhaps in future elections the requirements can be increased depending on the size of the community at that time.

Comment: I'd actually like to see Convention, but with the election already in progress that's probably not reasonable.  Next time, though?

Comment: @MonicaCellio If there is a next time. Besides, next time we can probably have more badge requirements than that because we will have grown.

Comment: Yeah, I'd been assuming that "election 2012" implied an "election 2013" and 2014 and... but maybe not.

Comment: I just saw the discussion in chat.  I hadn't realized how limiting my suggestion would be, so never mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Badge requirements are currently set up on Stack Overflow only where it helps narrow down the pool of viable candidates to manageable numbers.

Here, though, you only have four nominees for three positions so far. We certainly don't want to make it *harder* for anyone to nominate.

If you personally believe that the Quorum badge is essential, that's something you can use to guide your votes. Meta participation is displayed on every nomination and every nominee so far has the badge anyway.

Between that and the lack of apparent community support for this proposal, this is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) this time around.

Comment: I had been thinking of using the badge requirements less as a filter and more of an indicator for what qualities we are looking for. As you say, I wouldn't want to shrink the pool anymore, but I don't really think Quorum is shrinking it much. It does indicate somewhat what we are looking for. IAE thanks for your reply!